# how to round up or down with the If function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a number round up or round down depending on if it's higher or lower than 0.8

If the number in U6 is for example 16.8, I want cell V6 to round UP to 17.

If the number in U15 is 14.33 I want V15 to round DOWN to 14.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the number to be rounded will always be positive, then try:

```
=ROUND(U6-0.3,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple round formula like below.

```
=ROUND(U6,0)
```

`Round()` formula with `0` decimal place will automatically round up greater than `.5` to its upper integer and round down less than `.5` to lower integer.

Comment: if my number has 10.7 and i need to round down to 10.5 is there additional formula for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula.

`=INT(U6)+((U6-INT(U6))>=0.8)`

Depending on the condition put in `(U6-INT(U6))>=0.8` the formula will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` which will be coerced into `1` or `0` due to arithmetic operation.